# Need a customized index in the elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

My query is, if i search for a keyword "apparel" my current result is

```
{  
  "_index":"myindex",
  "_type":"pages",
  "_id":"www.abc.com",
  "_score":1.726047,
  "_source":{  
    "organization_website":"www.abc.com",
    "organization_values":[  
      {  
        "unpsc":15,
        "industry":"apparel",
        "codevalue":0.15
      },
      {  
        "unpsc":20,
        "industry":"textile",
        "codevalue":0.2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I can override the _score in Elasticsearch using  function score, but i need to add the add the score (which i have created) as the default score in the index. For instance if i search for the keyword "apparel", the default score will 1 , but i want to override the score of the apparel (which i have created) i.e unpsc value to the score.

Is this possible to create a index in the elasticsearch to refer an another node as a default score or i have go with the function score/ boost.....?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to assign a default score based on some value.

You'll have to use function score as suggested by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried with multiple option can't able to achieve it., have to stick with function score.